# Xcode change view from AppDelegate and UICollectionView delete cell

Tags: xcode, uicollectionview, segue, uicollectionviewcell, appdelegate

I'm asking this question only because I'm frustrated of searching for answers.

I have an app with a facebook login interface, and I want the root view controller to change if the user is already logged in to facebook.
I found out how to check if the user is logged in, but i can't seem to found how to change the rootViewcontroller from the AppDelegate properly.
The next view i wanna show has navigation controller so i wanna show it too.

The next problem I have is the I cant figure out how to add delete button to cells in UICollectionView.
I want it to be hidden and after long press on one of the cells , all the buttons will show up on the cells.
I figured out how to add the long press gesture , but not the buttons.

any help?
sorry if it's a dumm questions but im hopless right now.
thanks !

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
{
    [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            _userFacebookData = result;

            UIStoryboard *yourStoryB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
            PasscodeEnter *vc = [yourStoryB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"enter_password"];
            self.window.rootViewController = vc ;

        } else {
            NSLog(@"couldn't fetch the user data");
        }
    }];


}
else {
    // try to open session with existing valid token
    NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"public_profile", @"email",nil];
    FBSession *session = [[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions];
    [FBSession setActiveSession:session];
    if([FBSession openActiveSessionWithAllowLoginUI:NO]) {
        [FBRequestConnection startForMeWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                _userFacebookData = result;

                UIStoryboard *yourStoryB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
                PasscodeEnter *vc = [yourStoryB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"enter_password"];
                self.window.rootViewController = vc ;

            } else {
                NSLog(@"couldn't fetch the user data");
            }


        }];
    }
}

[FBLoginView class];
[FBProfilePictureView class];


return YES;
```

}

Comment: you using XIB's or Storyboard ?

Comment: I'm using Storyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your applicationDidFinishLaunching:

Use this code to change your initial View Controller,

```
UIStoryboard *yourStoryB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
_yourNavigationVC = [yourStoryB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyNavigationVC"];

self.window.rootViewController = _yourNavigationVC ;
```

Create a new ViewContoller in your Storyboard, and give it an identifier and use it. Hope, it helps.

And to detect, long press use this code in your cell :

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer* longPressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureHandler:)];
[longPressGesture setMinimumPressDuration:2.0];
[cell addGestureRecognizer:longPressGesture];


-(void)gestureHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
 {
    if(UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan == gesture.state)
    {
        UICollectionViewCell *cell = (UICollectionViewCell *)[[gesture view] superview];
        //Now add delete button.
   }
}
```

Hope, this helps.

Comment: thanks ! but when again , i have the same problem , the facebook login still shows before the pushed view controller . I will ad my code .
and the gesture give me an error "incompatible pointer types initializing" for the "cell" variable. any ideas?

Comment: And in your edited question, in both cases you are opening 'PasscodeEnter' view controller. Please mention via comments, where exactly you want to open your navigation controller.

Comment: my rootViewController right now is "Login", if the user has already logged in with facebook, i want that the rootViewController will be  'PasscodeEnter', 
both cases are checking if theres a connection to facebook, and if there isn't i want it to go to "Login"

Comment: and when i try to get the indexpath.row from the cell it gives me an error : 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UICollectionView _layoutAttributes]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Ok , i fixed the error with the gesture, still have the problem with the VC